# How to programmatically grant 'Read' permission to a Group/user for a particular list in sharepoint

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, permissions

**How to programmatically grant 'Read' permission to a Group/user for a particular list?**.

I have created a group in **Share Point manually**. 
Created a list too.

Now i want to add '**Read**' permission to the particular list for a particular group/user.

The webpart works fine.

But does not update the permission. 
Kindly help.

I am pasting the code below...

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox2.Text))
            {
                Label4.Text = "Please Enter Some Values";
                //Label4.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            }
            else
            {

                SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
                SPGroup group = web.SiteGroups[TextBox2.Text];
                SPWebApplication webApp = web.Site.WebApplication;
                webApp.FormDigestSettings.Enabled = false;
                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                SPRoleDefinition rDefination = web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Reader);
                 SPRoleAssignment rAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(group);

                rAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(rDefination);
                SPList list = web.Lists[TextBox1.Text];
                list.BreakRoleInheritance(true);
                //SPItem item = list.
                //item.RoleAssignments.Add(rAssignment);
                list.Update();
                Label4.Text = "Permission is successfully on item";
                //Label4.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                TextBox1.Text = string.Empty;
                TextBox2.Text = string.Empty;
                web.RoleAssignments.Add(rAssignment);
                web.Update();
                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                webApp.FormDigestSettings.Enabled = true;

            }
     }
```

Comment: I also face type of problem. I have a list with Read only permission and want to update the list on Page Load. Its work fine for admin user. But does not update the list for read only user.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this the code below. runwithelevatedprivileges will allow the simple user to update the list.

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox2.Text))
            {
                Label4.Text = "Please Enter Some Values";
                //Label4.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            }
            else
            {

                SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
                SPGroup group = web.SiteGroups[TextBox2.Text];
                SPWebApplication webApp = web.Site.WebApplication;
                webApp.FormDigestSettings.Enabled = false;
                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                SPRoleDefinition rDefination = web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Reader);
                 SPRoleAssignment rAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(group);

                rAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(rDefination);
                SPList list = web.Lists[TextBox1.Text];
                list.BreakRoleInheritance(true);
                //SPItem item = list.
                //item.RoleAssignments.Add(rAssignment);
                list.Update();
                Label4.Text = "Permission is successfully on item";
                //Label4.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                TextBox1.Text = string.Empty;
                TextBox2.Text = string.Empty;
                web.RoleAssignments.Add(rAssignment);
                web.Update();
                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                webApp.FormDigestSettings.Enabled = true;

            }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SPListItem listitem = listPositional.Items.Add();
                           listitem["Title"] = "data1";
                           //listitem["Enc"] = "Encrypted data";
                           listitem.Update();
                           listitem.BreakRoleInheritance(false);

                           SPGroup group = myWeb.SiteGroups["Restricted Readers"];

                                                         GrantPermission(listitem, myWeb, SPRoleType.Reader, group);


private static void GrantPermission(SPListItem CurrentListItem, SPWeb oSPWeb, SPRoleType SPRoleType, SPPrincipal SPPrincipal)
    {

        try
        {

            //Create one Role Definition i.e Full Controls, Contribute rights or Read rights etc.
            SPRoleDefinition oSPRoleDefinition = oSPWeb.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType);
            //Create one Role Assignment for the specified SP user or group.
            SPRoleAssignment oSPRoleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(SPPrincipal);
            //Bind the role definition to the role assignment object created for the user or group.
            oSPRoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(oSPRoleDefinition);
            //Add it to the specified list item.
            CurrentListItem.RoleAssignments.Add(oSPRoleAssignment);
            //update the list item so that specified user assignment will have the access.
            CurrentListItem.Update();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;

        }
        }
```